# Результат из секции EXISTS

Tags: mysql

У меня есть запрос

```
SELECT 
  IF (
    EXISTS (
      SELECT 
        name_short,
        name_full,
        ...
      FROM
        (SELECT 
          ...
        FROM
          ...
        WHERE ...
        GROUP BY ...
        ORDER BY ...) a 
      UNION
      ALL 
      SELECT 
        name_short,
        name_full,
        ...
      FROM
        (SELECT 
          ...
        FROM
          ...
        WHERE ...
        GROUP BY ...
        ORDER BY ...) b
    ) = 0,
    'empty set',
    'not empty set'
  ) ;
```

Он работает правильно, и в случае, если запрос внутри функции `EXISTS` возвращает пустую строку, выдаёт сообщение `'empty set`', иначе - строку `'not empty set'`.
Я же хочу получить значения полей `name_short` и `name_full` в случае, если запрос внутри функции `EXISTS` возвращает данные (а не пустую строку). Как это можно сделать, не дублируя код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить сделать вот так:

```
(
SELECT 1 as 'is_exists'
    name_short,
    name_full,
/* и так далее */
    limit 1
)
union all
(
select 0 as 'is_exists', null, null
)
limit 1
```

Но только если надо получить одну запись. `limit 1` обязателен для корректной работы в обоих местах.
Или вот так можно:

```
select (is_exists_table.name_short is not null) as is_exists,
    name_short,
    name_full
from (
    select 1 -- just any one row
) anyrow left join (
    select name_short, name_full
        from /* остальной запрос */
) is_exists_table ON TRUE
```

Вернёт все записи по условию либо одну запись с `is_exists = 0` и остальными полями `NULL`. Если `name_short` может быть `NULL` сам по себе, то выберите какое-нибудь другое поле `not null`